# Non-nullable instance field 'categoryTitle' must be initialized. Try adding an initializer expression or a generative constructor that initializes it

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I am not understanding how to solve this error because If I mark it late an exception is thrown and the field hasn't been initialized. I am new to flutter so if someone could help that would be nice. I am trying to remove the item with id when the page pops. I converted the stateless to stateful widget. I was following a lecture and did the same but it's not working for me.

```
  class CategoryMealScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/categories -meals';

  @override
  State<CategoryMealScreen> createState() => _CategoryMealScreenState();
}

class _CategoryMealScreenState extends State<CategoryMealScreen> {
  String categoryTitle ;
  late List<Meal> displayedMeals;
  bool _loadedInitData = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState(); 
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    if (_loadedInitData == false) {
      final routeArgs = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map<
          String, String>; 
      final categoryTitle = routeArgs['title'] as String;
      final categoryId = routeArgs['id'];
      displayedMeals = DUMMY_MEALS.where((Meal) {
        return Meal.categories.contains(
            categoryId);
      }).toList();
      _loadedInitData = true;
    }

    super
        .didChangeDependencies(); 
  }

  void _removeMeal(String mealId) {
    setState(() {
      displayedMeals.removeWhere((meal) =>
          meal.id ==
          mealId); 
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(categoryTitle),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
          return MealItem(
            id: displayedMeals[index].id,
            title: displayedMeals[index].title,
            complexity: displayedMeals[index].complexity,
            duration: displayedMeals[index].duration,
            imageUrl: displayedMeals[index].imageUrl,
            affordability: displayedMeals[index].affordability,
            removeItem: _removeMeal,
          );
        },
        itemCount: displayedMeals.length,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Initialize your categoryTile variable this way `String? categoryTitle ;` or `String categoryTitle = '';`

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace:

```
late List<Meal> displayedMeals;
```

with

```
List?<Meal> displayedMeals;
```